# Java: Accessing fields in Downloaded Object

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, but know Objective-C.  I need to access fields < keys, values > in a downloaded Object.

Below is the code:

`car` is an `Schema` and `car_id` is the field to query

```
Map<String, List<SMObject>> feedback = new HashMap<String, List<SMObject>>();
List<SMCondition> query = new ArrayList<SMCondition>();
DataService ds = serviceProvider.getDataService();
List<SMObject> results;

try {
            query.add(new SMEquals("car_id", new SMString(make)));
            results = ds.readObjects("car", query);

            if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
                feedback.put(make, results);
            }

    }
....
```

results is an Object downloaded from a remote Database that is basically a HashMap.  Assuming there is only one object that is returned each time, what would be the code to access Key & Values in the returned results object?

[Complete Code in case you want to see it.](https://github.com/stackmob/stackmob-customcode-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackmob/example/CRUD/QueryByField.java)

**EDIT**

Can I do something like this:

```
    SMObject resultObj;

     if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
            resultObj = results[0];
            resultObj.put("resolved", "1");
            resultObj.put("accepted", "1");
            resultObj.put("declined", "0");

            String model = (String)resultObj.get("model");
        }
```

Comment: That completely depends on what your `SMObject` class is.

Comment: If this question is about iterating the map, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/46898/260633. That being said it is unclear what object you are referring to in the question. The `Map` or the `SMObject`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sorry.  results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted all the keys, you would do:

```
Map<String, List<SMObject>> feedback = new HashMap<String, List<SMObject>>();
List<String> myKeys = feedback.keySet();
```

To get the values, you would use the `get` method:

```
Map<String, List<SMObject>> feedback = new HashMap<String, List<SMObject>>();
feedback.get("yourKey");
```

For more info, check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

EDIT:

```
SMObject resultObj;

 if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
        List<SMObject> myResults = feedback.get(make); 
        resultObj = myResults.get(0);
        resultObj.put("resolved", "1");
        resultObj.put("accepted", "1");
        resultObj.put("declined", "0");

        String model = (String)resultObj.get("model");
    }
```

The general concept is that you use the key, to get the value from the `hashMap`. That value happens to be a list of objects; therefore, you need to iterate over that list as well and retrieve each object from the list.

Comment: Thanks!  Just to clarify, I was under the impression that results is a type of Array of objects.  'make' is the key that calls that array.  Will your code allow me to access the results[0] and it's <keys, values> ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. You could use `mResults = feedback.get(make);` would return the array of objects, at which point you would use `mResults[0]` to get that first result.

Comment: I'm lost on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to add keys/values to the list, or retrieve them?

Comment: If myResults is a `List`, you'd have to use `myResults.get(0)` to get by index. `myResults[0]` will only work for an array. Other than that, Blaine's approach looks good. And it is conceivable that `SMObject` wraps an internal HashMap but offers a different external API -- if `put(key)` is not available, look for `putString(key)`, `setAttribute(key)`, `set(key)` or other similar keyed put/set/add methods.

Comment: @ThomasW, you're right. In my haste, I forgot about that. I've updated. Thanks.